# Count adjacent dates in array

Tags: c#, arrays, adjacency-list

I have an array of about 1000 records, each record is an object with these properties:

```
- Result
    + Number: Integer (can repeat, not an ID)
    + Date: DateTime
```

I want to count and get the most of Result that has adjacent Date.
Can anyone give any idea?

**EDIT:**
For example:

```
I have an array:
List<Result> results = new List<Result> {
    new Result(){ Number = 34, Date = "7/15/2011" },
    new Result(){ Number = 59, Date = "7/15/2011" },
    new Result(){ Number = 11, Date = "7/15/2011" },

    new Result(){ Number = 1, Date = "7/16/2011" },
    new Result(){ Number = 3, Date = "7/16/2011" },
    new Result(){ Number = 34, Date = "7/16/2011" },

    new Result(){ Number = 98, Date = "7/17/2011" },
    new Result(){ Number = 34, Date = "7/17/2011" },
    new Result(){ Number = 29, Date = "7/17/2011" },
    new Result(){ Number = 99, Date = "7/17/2011" },
    new Result(){ Number = 1, Date = "7/17/2011" },

    new Result(){ Number = 31, Date = "7/18/2011" },
    new Result(){ Number = 76, Date = "7/18/2011" },
    new Result(){ Number = 47, Date = "7/18/2011" },
    new Result(){ Number = 34, Date = "7/18/2011" },

    new Result(){ Number = 99, Date = "7/19/2011" },
    new Result(){ Number = 0, Date = "7/19/2011" },
    new Result(){ Number = 88, Date = "7/19/2011" },
    new Result(){ Number = 33, Date = "7/19/2011" }
};

As you see, all i want is to get:
- Number = 34 with 4 adjacent days 
- Number = 1 with 2 adjacent days
```

Comment: By adjacent you mean, for some datetime parameter you want datetime + 1 -1 day results?

Comment: Your English is fine, however note the formatting and Title that I've changed to reflect your true question.

Comment: @Aseem Gautam: i mean date +1 day is adjacent

Answer (score 1):

```
var HighestAdjacentDate =
    Results.OrderByDescending(Result => 
        Results.Count(R => 
            Math.Abs((R.Date - Result.Date).Days) == 1)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: So what's about 3 or 4 dates is adjacent? and i want to count them and take the most

Comment: That's what the orderby is for. It'll order by the number of adjacent dates, then return the first (most dates adjacent).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, for brevity, ordered input

```
var sample = new [] {
    new { Number = 1, Date = DateTime.Now },
    new { Number = 2, Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5) },
    new { Number = 3, Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(6) },
    new { Number = 4, Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(9) }
};

var adjacent = sample
    .Where((o,i) => i>0 && (o.Date.Date - sample[i-1].Date.Date).Days<=1);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", adjacent));
```

For this particular input shows

```
H:\>csharp test.cs
{ Number = 3, Date = 7/21/2011 12:19:44 PM }
```